# Polynomial roots and Viète's formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

Suppose we have $a_{i}\in \mathbb{C}$ for $1\leq i \leq k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and WLOG that $a_{1}$ has a magnitude at least as large as any other $a_{i}$. Then let $\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}^{n}=A$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. It can be shown that for large $n$, $a_{1}$ is approximately an $n$th root of $A$. This is assuming that some circumstances are avoided, like $n=2$ with $a_{1}=-a_{2}$.

So if a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ has $m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ complex roots, $r_{1}, r_{2}, ... , r_{m}$, then for large $n$, the root with the largest magnitude will approximately be an $n$th root of $R=\sum_{i=1}^{m}r_{i}^{n}.$ Hypothetically, one could simply express $R$ as an expression of the coefficients of $p$ using Viète's formulas, check $p$ when evaluated at the $n$th roots of the expression, and approximate the largest root to an arbitrary degree. Then, the factor could be divided out of $p$ and the process could be iterated until all roots are sufficiently approximated.

My question is, can $R$ be expressed as an expression using Viète's formulas for arbitrary $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$? I imagine the expression would involve something like $(r_{1}+r_{2}+...+r_{m})^{\frac{1}{n}}-$ some stuff $=(-\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_{m}})^{\frac{1}{n}}-$ some stuff, where $a_{j}$ is the coefficient of $x^{j}$ in the polynomial.

Comment: Looks awfully like [Bernoulli's method](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bernoulli_method).

Comment: That's really cool! Thanks for showing me that. Is my method in any way equivalent to Bernoulli's method?

Comment: I haven't analyzed your method in detail, but the ideas seem the same.